# ¿por que no jala el include dinamico php?

Tags: php, html, web

Estoy haciendo una pagina web, en el index tengo unos includes como el header,menu,footer.

En la parte del menú(que esta en otro archivo html) tengo unos módulos que irán (administrador,inventario),
bueno lo importante es que el menú envia una por un a con href por ejemplo una palabra y en el index lo cacho y escribe ese modulo,

Bueno en xampp si funciona pero cuando estoy en linux no, aun no se por que aquí dejo el código.

-------Menu--------------

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree"><br><br>
    <li class="header" style='color:white;'>MODULOS DISPONIBLES</li>
    <li >
      <a href='home' >
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i> <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inicio</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href='admin'>
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i> <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Administrador</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li >
      <a href="inventario">
        <i class="fa fa-th fa-2x"></i> <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inventario</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ventas">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i> <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ventas</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

------Index que lo recibe-------

```
div class="content-wrapper " id='contentPrincipal'>
<?php
  if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){
          if($_GET["ruta"] == "admin" || $_GET["ruta"] == "inventario" || $_GET["ruta"] == "ventas"){
             include "view/".$_GET["ruta"].".template.php";
          }
          else
            if($_GET["ruta"] == "home")
              include "view/home.template.php";
            else
              include "view/modules/404.template.php";
        }
        else
          include "view/home.template.php";

?>
```

Cabe aclarar que ya intente con este metodo

https://voragine.net/weblogs/como-pasar-variables-de-una-pagina-a-otra-en-una-web-con-php

y nada, no se por que en linux no me funciona si no tiene que ver con el SO o almenos que haga falta algo.

Comment: Probablemente xampp sea capaz de interpretar el href con la ruta que necesitas, pero lampp no. Prueba a poner la ruta completa (página y variable) en el href, tal y como se ve en el ejemplo que has utilizado: http://url.pagina.destino/?ruta="admin".

Comment: Gracias por contestar...Si ya lo hice pero solo por ejemplo admin pongo
index.php/?ruta="admin" pero me direcciona al  index sin los stylos,scrips,etc y no incluye la parte del admin

Comment: Estas omitiendo algo. ¿Donde aparece `ruta` en el HTML? ¿que más contiene el .php que procesa la página?

Comment: amm si exacto igual me di cuenta igual de ruta, pero ya lo puse y tampoco, lo que me extraña es que en xampp como si fuciona, el .php que procesa manda a llamar los css,js, y codigo html para poner otras cositas

Comment: Y no te da ningún error de que la ruta este mal o algo?

Comment: Usa constantes y haz las rutas absolutas desde la raíz. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: Luis, lo que te quería decir en mi comentario es que enseñes **todo** el HTML (en especial la parte donde aparece  `ruta`) y que muestres **todo** el código php. Está claro que pasas algo por alto y por tanto, al explicarlo con palabras, no das toda la información que necesitamos.

Answer (score 0):

En linux debes tener cuidado con las mayusculas en los nombres de los archivos y con los permisos.
Asegurate que tus archivos tengan los permisos adecuados ejecutando esto:

```
cd /ruta/a/mi/codigo
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} + 
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
```

1. primero usando la consola ve a la ruta de tu codigo
2. cambia los permisos de las capetas a los correctos
3. cambia los permisos de los ficheros a los correctos